# Using random variables inside Arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays

First of all, sorry if this is worded poorly, as I'm a beginner at code.

I'm currently working on an online computer science course, however I'm quite confused on how to do one small part. We need to use arrays for this activity, where the user has multiple selections and each different selection has a different/unique text output. Everything works fine, except I need an option to choose a random selection, however I'm a bit confused on how to make it. You can see from my code the options 1-8. I want it to randomly select one of the selections.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$train[0] = "Canada";
$train[1] = "Sahara Desert";
$train[2] = "Russia";
$train[3] = "Chernobyl";
$train[4] = "United States";
$train[5] = "North Korea";
$train[6] = "Germany";
$train[7] = "Hawaii";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
Took out everything here, it's not important.
</head>

    <body>
        <center>
    <h1>Vacation Time!</h1>

    <h4>You and your family just won the lottery! You all want to go on vacation, but nobody can agree where to go. Inside each train cart has a card with a location written on it. Whatever you find is where you're going! </h4>

        <form name="form1" action="activity-2-7-arrays-a.php" method="post">

            <label>Which cart on the train do you want to choose?</label>
            <br>
            <select name="cart" required>
                <option value="1">First Cart</option>
                <option value="2">Second Cart</option>
                <option value="3">Third Cart</option>
                <option value="4">Fourth Cart</option>
                <option value="5">Fifth Cart</option>
                <option value="6">Sixth Cart</option>
                <option value="7">Seventh Cart</option>
                <option value="8">Eight Cart</option>
                <option value="show">Show all options</option>
                <option value="any">Choose Randomly</option>
                <br>
            </select><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="subButton" class="subButton" value="Go!"/><br/>
            </form>

    <h1><u>Final Results</u></h1>

<?php
if($_POST['subButton']) {
    $cart = $_POST['cart'];
    $roll = rand(1,9);

    if($cart == show) {
        for($x = 1; $x <= 9; $x++) {
            echo "<p> You could have ender up in... </p>";
            echo "<h2> " . $train[$x] . "</h2>";
        }
        return;
    }
    echo "<h2>"."Well, it looks like you're going to " . $train[$cart] . "! Have fun! </h2>";
}
return;

if ($cart == $roll) {

}
echo "<h2>"."Can't handle the pressure? You were selected to go to  " . $train[$roll] . "! Have fun! </h2>";
?>
```

I'm sure it's a bit messy, also. Hopefully you understand what I mean. If you're able to explain the answer to me that would be extremely helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: Your test `if ($cart == $roll)` is wrong. You are comparing the user's selection to the random number you just generated. Look at your other if statements closely, and I think you can figure it out.

Comment: There are a few problems with the code: First you should change `if($cart == show)` to `if($cart == 'show')`. Second, you should define $train as an array so put `$train = array()` at the top. To answer your question, I think you should use `array_shuffle()` on $train to randomize the list.

Comment: You should put `array_shuffle($train);` before you echo the result ("Well it looks like you're going to..."). Also, all the stuff under the second `return;` statement will not run because of the `return;`, but you don't need that anyways.

Comment: No need to shuffle the array, based OP's question.  OP just needs to randomly choose one of them. `rand(1,9)` is good enough

Comment: @JoelLee But then there is no need for the user to select a cart number.

Comment: do you need to select random selection inside html drop-down field? or you need to show a line after the html-form "Can't handle ... blah-blah-blah..." ? Here is some problems in the code, you have to `return` for what and why? and you have no closed html-tags

Comment: @Andrew - yeah.... OP's requirements are a bit vague.  I took it to mean that choices 1-8 would each show the same result *always*. But if the user selects the "Choose randomly", they would get a random result from the fixed eight available. I interpreted it that way because if you also randomize the array each time, then there isn't much point in having an option to choose randomly from an already random array.

Comment: @JoelLee ooh yes you are correct. I didn't notice the random option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are randomly generating a value regardless of the user choice and comparing it with user's selection and other weird things.

```
<?php
if($_POST['subButton']) {
    $cart = $_POST['cart'];
    $roll = rand(1,9);
```

You are generating a random value before even checking if user selected 'Choose randomly' and why generate a random between 1 and 9? Your `$train` array starts with index 0 and ends with index 7.

```
    if($cart == show) {
```

String needs to be quoted.

```
        for($x = 1; $x <= 9; $x++) {
```

Again looping `$x` from 1 to 9 makes no sense because of your array indexes.

```
            echo "<p> You could have ender up in... </p>";
            echo "<h2> " . $train[$x] . "</h2>";
```

Will fail when `$x` reaches 8 since last index in `$train` is 7.

```
        }
        return;
    } 
    echo "<h2>"."Well, it looks like you're going to " . $train[$cart] . "! Have fun! </h2>";
    }
    return;
```

So if user didn't select 'Show all options' you show him his chosen location. If user chose 'Select Randomly' this will fail since `$cart` would have value 'any' and `$train['any']` does not exist.

Here is code with correct logic.

```
<?php
if($_POST['subButton']) {
    $cart = $_POST['cart'];
    if ($cart == 'any') {// Check if user selected 'Choose Randomly'
        $roll = rand(0, 7);
        echo "<h2>"."Can't handle the pressure? You were selected to go to  " .  $train[$roll] . "! Have fun! </h2>";
    }
    else {
        if ($cart == 'show') { // If user selected 'Show all options'
            echo "<p> You could have ender up in... </p>";
            for($x = 0; $x <= 7; $x++) {
                echo "<h2> " . $train[$x] . "</h2>";
            }
        }
        else { // User selected cart so show him chosen location
            echo "<h2>"."Well, it looks like you're going to " . $train[$cart] . "! Have fun! </h2>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some problems in the code

1. from where and why we `return`?
2. no closing html-tags

I would change the last part of php-code like that:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['subButton']) {
    $cart = $_POST['cart'];
    $value = intval($cart);
    $roll = mt_rand(1, 8); // mt_rand() has more entropy than rand()

    if ($cart == 'show') {
        // show target locations (according the OP-source)
        for($x = 1; $x <= 8; $x++) {
            echo "<p> You could have ender up in... </p>";
            echo "<h2> " . $train[$x-1] . "</h2>";
        }
    } else if ($value > 0 && $value <= 8) {
        echo "<h2>"."Well, it looks like you're going to " . $train[$value-1] . "! Have fun! </h2>";
        // idk why it needed, but move it here
        if ($value == $roll) {
        }
    } else if ($cart == 'any') {
        echo "<h2>"."Can't handle the pressure? You were selected to go to  " . $train[$roll-1] . "! Have fun! </h2>";
    } else {
        // $_POST['cart'] has something wrong
    }
}
?>
<!-- lines below was added to close html-tags -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand):

```
$random = array_rand($train);
```

Comment: This solves a different problem than OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @JoelLee Touche - too early in the morning here!

Comment: @Darren You mean *"Touché"* - hahaha, sorry, the devil made me do it. *grin*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hahahah you cheeky sh*t! I chose to be *"keyboard boring"* this time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `rand()` use `mt_rand()` because the [PHP DOCUMENTATION](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) literally says

> mt_rand — Generate a better random value

Regarding your php code, you have a lot of errors. This is how your bottom php code should look:

```
<?php
  if($_POST['subButton']) 
  {
    $cart = $_POST['cart'];
    $roll = mt_rand(0,7);
       //0-7 because those are the values you inserted into
       //the $train[] array

    if($cart == 'show') {
      //another correction here, it has to be 0-7
      for($x = 0; $x <= 7; $x++) {
        echo "<p> You could have ender up in... </p>";
        echo "<h2> " . $train[$x] . "</h2>";
      }
    } 
    else if ($cart!='any')
    {
       "<h2>Well, it looks like you're going to " . $train[$cart] . "! Have fun! </h2>";
    }
    else //took out return and placed an else
    {
        echo "<h2>Well, it looks like you're going
        to " . $train[$cart] . "! Have fun! </h2>";
    }

?>
```